# G++ Linux shows a warning "use of incomplete type" inside a template that MSVC does not. can I disable this warning?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have two files, `test.cpp` and `foo.h`.
test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo;

foo* fooInstance;
template<typename T> T bar() {

    return fooInstance->template barInternal<T>();

}

#include "foo.h"

int main() {

    fooInstance = new foo();
    std::cout << bar<int>();

    return 0;

}
```

and foo.h:

```
class foo {

public:
    template<typename T> T barInternal() {

        return T(5);

    }

};
```

This code compiles without issue on MSVC Windows, and on Linux (Manjaro KDE) using G++ it also compiles and runs without issue, however, it throws this annoying warning.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘T bar()’:
test.cpp:8:23: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class foo’
8 |     return fooInstance->template barInternal<T>();
  |                       ^~
test.cpp:3:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class foo’
3 | class foo;
  |
```

Why does it throw a warning on G++ and how can I get rid of the warning (either changing the code or somehow disabling the warning since it seems useless)

Comment: Without a declaration of the `foo` class, how is it supposed to know that it has a `barInternal` member function?

Comment: @Barmar I know, I understand that, however it does compile, and it does work both on G++ and MSVC, just G++ for some reason throws this annoying warning and I was wondering how to either stop it from showing up or fixing it somehow

Comment: @user4581301 I just updated the question, I added the MRE and it literally works, everything works as it should, yet it still throws the annoying, seemingly useless warning. (Since it literally compiles and does what it should)

Comment: move `#include "foo.h"` to the top of the file.

Comment: @stark I can not, the real problem I am having is way more complex and is spanning multiple files, so everything before #include "foo.h" is supposed to be like in a different file. And I cannot move the include because bar is in a header, and foo.h includes that header, so the compiler will not let me do that.

Comment: Groovy. Thanks. OK it works because `foo` is fully defined by the time the compiler instantiates the template. Clang flat-out hates it. G++ is telling you that you're at risk and only seems to be placated enough by the addition of `template` to allow it at all. Visual Studio is quite happy.  A better language lawyer than me will know whether the standard approves of this or not.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought, it also makes sense. It is just annoying because I unfortunately cannot do it differently and since it is in a header file that is included a lot I get a lot of the same warning that just makes a mess out of the terminal

Comment: Why does `foo.h` need to include the header that contains `bar`? Can you show an example that resembles the file structure of your real code?

Comment: This seems like a big code smell. Do you have enough control over your code that you can move the template into its own include file and #include it where needed?

Comment: @Bodo Simply, the bar function is inside a class, and foo.h uses that class

Comment: @JosephLarson I do, It is just that this is code for my project that is a open source header only library, plus the only issue is the warning, the code works so for me there is no reason to edit the code

Comment: I suggest to add a link to the open source header only library and add a [mre] based on this library. Showing an example that is closer to your real code might help to find a solution.

Comment: "This code compiles without issue on MSVC Windows" [No it doesn't really](https://godbolt.org/z/Wa65rWhGn). It only compiles if you do not specify a reasnably recent C++ standard, which in MSVC speak means "accept all kinds of invalid code and shut up about it".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this particular warning has no corresponding warning flag, so the only way to disable it in GCC is using the `-w` flag, which unconditionally disables all warnings and cannot be overridden by `-Wxxxx` flags.

The reason (I assume) why this warning has no corresponding warning flag is that it actually diagnoses an ill-formed situation: your code is in violation of the standard. This, incidentally, is also the reason why Clang flat-out refuses to compile it.

The relevant rule here is [[temp.res.general]/6.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.4):

> [...] The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: [...] a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter [...]

In this case, a hypothetical instantiation of `bar` immediately following its definition would be ill-formed because, at that point, `foo` is still incomplete. Even if you only plan to instantiate the template at a point where `foo` is complete, the fact remains that the code is ill-formed (no diagnostic required) according to the standard.

This can be worked around by adding an extra template parameter to `bar` that will be defaulted to `fooInstance`:

```
template<typename T, auto* p = fooInstance> T bar() {
    return p->template barInternal<T>();
}
```

Now, whether or not `p` points to an incomplete type depends on the particular `p`, so the "due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter" condition is no longer met.

You can still call `bar<int>()` as you currently do; it means `bar<int, fooInstance>()` due to the default template argument.